# Уникальность комбинации внешних ключей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

ORM генерирует таблицу friends в СУБД mysql, используя следующую sql инструкцию. Таблица реализует список подписок одного пользователя на блоги других.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testdatabase`.`friends` (
 `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `CurrentUserId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `PickedUserId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
 INDEX `IX_Friends_CurrentUserId` (`CurrentUserId` ASC) INVISIBLE,
 INDEX `IX_Friends_PickedUserId` (`PickedUserId` ASC) VISIBLE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Friends_Users_CurrentUserId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CurrentUserId`)
    REFERENCES `cyberdatabase`.`users` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Friends_Users_PickedUserId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PickedUserId`)
    REFERENCES `cyberdatabase`.`users` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 8
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Требуется обеспечить уникальность записей по комбинации полей - пользователь не должен иметь возможности подписаться дважды.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли обеспечить уникальность, используя инструкцию ALTER TABLE?

Comment: А для чего тут нужно поле `Id`? Оно где-нибудь используется? Может, проще сделать составной первичный ключ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `testdatabase`.`friends`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (CurrentUserId, PickedUserId)
```